# ASP application state

Tags: asp.net

I have in file Global.asax in the event Application_Start the code:

```
{ 
   Application["orderId"]=0
}
```

Then I use it in newOrder.aspx.cs in button addOrder_click to increment it and I copy the URL of this project in Visual Studio 2010 and paste it in many pages to see if more than user add new order. It was fine when I try the increment of application["orderId"] in the first page I loaded but when I open another page to act that I another person the database says:

"Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.theOrder"

Which means application["orderId"] initialize with zero another time.
Sorry for lots of lines and I have trouble with explaining my problem.

Sorry! Help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you restart your application, your order id will be reset to 0.  If you're using this as your primary key, then you'll get collisions.

Instead of trying to keep track of the order id in the application, use a auto-increment field, and return the value when you insert a new order into the database.

Comment: I didnot restart my application it is runnin and i copy the url in many pages to see if another user add new order

Comment: this is the way to test application I Know i don know if its right way

Comment: You dont need to restart your applicaiton.  It does it automatically.  My answer has a link explaining it, but here it is again.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx

Comment: +1 because your answer is correct, and more concise than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The Application is the wrong place to keep track of something that needs to be persisted and never duplicated.  The Application pool resets and recycles under any number of conditions, and every time that happens, the orderid will rever to to 0.

There a re many things that can cause the Application to reset - see this blog for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx

Instead of using the Application, you should let the database manage the order id.

If the orderId is in a database, then you should set the orderid column to be an Identity (auto-incrementing columns) and have the database keep track of the orderid.  Where inserting a new record, let the DB handle it and retrieve the newly generated orderId.

Assuming the table has only the following columns (and further assuming that this is a SQL Server):

```
OrderID int identy (Primary key)
OrderDate datetime
Customerid int (Foreign keym but known at order time)
```

your insert statement would look like this:

```
Insert into Orders (OrderDate, Customerid) VALUES (GetDate(), @Customerid);Select @@SCOPE_IDENTITY as NewOrderId From Orders;
```

For more on @@Scope_Identity, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx